# Interactive progress bar in CartoVL

Tags: carto, carto-vl, progress

I am creating an animated time series map using Carto VL and have included a progress bar that updates as the animation progresses. The bar updates, but is not interactive — for instance, a viewer would not be able to use the bar to advance or move backward in the animation. What could I change to make the progress bar interactive?

Here is the code I used to build the progress bar:

```
Progress: <input type="range" id="js-progress-range" min="-21000" max="0" step="500"></p>
```

...and here is how I update the progress bar using my animation:

```
function updateProgress () {
            $progressRange.value = alnusViz.variables.animation.getProgressValue();
}
  setInterval(updateProgress, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example from CARTO-VL's documentation on animation controls: [Interactive progress bar in CartoVL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333178/interactive-progress-bar-in-cartovl).

Basically, what you need to do is to use [`setCurrent`](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/reference/#expressionsanimationsetcurrent) method to update the animation when your progress bar control is dragged:

```js
$progressRange.addEventListener('change', () => {
  alnusViz.variables.animation.setCurrent($progressRange.value);
});
```

And to avoid updating it every 100ms, you should use layer's update event:

```js
layer.on('updated', () => {
    $progressRange.value = viz.variables.animation.getProgressValue();
});
```